# How to toggle elements?

Tags: angular

I have this in template:

```
<ul class="itme-flow-title sticky">
    <li>Zahtjev / Stavka <i (click)="filter(1)" class="fa fa-filter"></i> <input *ngIf="showFilter==='1'" type="text"></li>
    <li>Usluga <i (click)="filter(2)" class="fa fa-filter"></i><input *ngIf="showFilter==='2'" type="text"></li>
    <li>Broj telefona <i (click)="filter(3)" class="fa fa-filter"></i><input *ngIf="showFilter==='3'" type="text"></li>
</ul>
```

In ts i have this:

```
filter(filterNumb){
    this.showFilter = filterNumb;
}
```

Now what i want is also when user click again on same icon to close this input. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: this plunker might help https://plnkr.co/edit/RjdkUlWBoIAGOJPLrjCp?p=preview. do something like this

Comment: i have multiple elements...here is only one

Comment: you want the same button to toggle for all ?

Comment: you only want to show one element at a time ?

Comment: yes...but if user already clicked on that element to hide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solve it. If not I need **more info**.

```
filter(filterNumb){
  if(this.showFilter !== filterNumb) {
    this.showFilter = filterNumb;
  }
  else { this.showFilter = '0'; }
}
```